# How to fit a cylinder to scattered 3D XYZ point data in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, surface, point-clouds

I was wondering if it was possible for someone to provide me with some code examples for working with scattered XYZ point data in MATLAB Curve Fitting Toolbox? I would like to fit a surface to points that approximate a cylinder.

Thanks.

Comment: Have no experience, but have you looked at the links from the Matlab [Surface fitting page](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/surface-fitting.html)?

Answer (score 5):

*In Matlab R2015b and above,* You can use [`pcfitcylinder`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcfitcylinder.html) to fit a cylinder to a [`pointCloud`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pointcloud-class.html) object. Let's start with producing an example data to see how it works:

```
[theta, r, h] = meshgrid(0:.1:6.28, 1, 0:.2:4); % making a cylinder
r = r + 0.05 * randn(size(r)); % adding some radial noise
[x, y, z] = pol2cart(theta, r, h); % transforming the coordinate system
P = (rotx(60) * [x(:), y(:), z(:)]')'; % rotating the data points around x axis
figure;
scatter3(P(:, 1), P(:, 2), P(:, 3))
axis equal
```

[image]

The point cloud object is created as follows:

```
ptCloud = pointCloud(P);
```

Then the model can be fitted:

```
maxDistance = 0.02;
model = pcfitcylinder(ptCloud, maxDistance);
hold on
plot(model)
```

[image]

Depending on your data, to get a reasonable cylinder you might need to take a look at `pcfitcylinder` and consider including other input arguments.

Comment: Yay for fancy plots