# Fit a cylinder to scattered 3D XYZ point data

Tags: python, geometry, surface, point-clouds

As in the title, I want to fit a cylinder to a group of 3D points with Python. This is a nice [solution with MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39589384/how-to-fit-a-cylinder-to-scattered-3d-xyz-point-data-in-matlab). How can we do it with Python?

[image]

Comment: You could convert the matlab function?

Comment: The Matlab function is quite complicated. I hope we have a library that supports this function (or with minimal code) using Python.

Answer (score 5):

Using scipy.optimize.leastsq, we can create an error function in which the difference between the observed cylinder radius and the modelled radius is minimized. The following is an example of fitting a vertical cylinder

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq


def cylinderFitting(xyz,p,th):

    """
    This is a fitting for a vertical cylinder fitting
    Reference:
    http://www.int-arch-photogramm-remote-sens-spatial-inf-sci.net/XXXIX-B5/169/2012/isprsarchives-XXXIX-B5-169-2012.pdf

    xyz is a matrix contain at least 5 rows, and each row stores x y z of a cylindrical surface
    p is initial values of the parameter;
    p[0] = Xc, x coordinate of the cylinder centre
    P[1] = Yc, y coordinate of the cylinder centre
    P[2] = alpha, rotation angle (radian) about the x-axis
    P[3] = beta, rotation angle (radian) about the y-axis
    P[4] = r, radius of the cylinder

    th, threshold for the convergence of the least squares

    """   
    x = xyz[:,0]
    y = xyz[:,1]
    z = xyz[:,2]

    fitfunc = lambda p, x, y, z: (- np.cos(p[3])*(p[0] - x) - z*np.cos(p[2])*np.sin(p[3]) - np.sin(p[2])*np.sin(p[3])*(p[1] - y))**2 + (z*np.sin(p[2]) - np.cos(p[2])*(p[1] - y))**2 #fit function
    errfunc = lambda p, x, y, z: fitfunc(p, x, y, z) - p[4]**2 #error function 

    est_p , success = leastsq(errfunc, p, args=(x, y, z), maxfev=1000)

    return est_p

if __name__=="__main__":

    np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)    
    xyz = np.loadtxt('cylinder11.xyz')
    #print xyz
    print "Initial Parameters: "
    p = np.array([-13.79,-8.45,0,0,0.3])
    print p
    print " "

    print "Performing Cylinder Fitting ... "
    est_p =  cylinderFitting(xyz,p,0.00001)
    print "Fitting Done!"
    print " "


    print "Estimated Parameters: "
    print est_p
```

Comment: Just a remark but the **th** parameter is ignored inside the function.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how exactly did you come up with this function?

Answer (score 4):

There is paper at David Eberly site ["Fitting 3D Data with a Cylinder"](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/CylinderFitting.pdf) that describes math basics and shows pseudocode.

You can also refer to C++ code in Geometric Tools Engine at the same site. I think that some auxiliary math functions like matrix inverse etc could be implemented in NymPy.

Answer (score 2):

[Cylinder Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJSqj.png)

I had a similar situation of fitting a cylinder through several points. we measure the gap between 2 cylinders using a gap sensor at several points and I had to visualize how gap varies in comparison with the cylinder.

I used ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, alpha=0.5) where x , y, z are numpy arrays of 3D location of all the points. Take a look at image below.

code snippet,

```
# Extract X,Y,Z values from the sensor data 
for i in range(num_of_sensors):
  ax.scatter(x[:,i], y[:,i], z[:,i], color = "k", marker=".", s=5, cmap='hot')
  ax.text(x[0,i]+ 10, y[0,i] + 10, z[0,i]+100, '%s' % (idx[i]), size=5, zorder=1, color='b') 

# plot the surface
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, alpha=0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

This [repo](https://github.com/xingjiepan/cylinder_fitting) by xingjiepan allows you to compute the best fit cylinder using Python.

The algorithm is by [David Eberly](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/LeastSquaresFitting.pdf).

As stated by David Eberly, the main assumption is that the underlying data is modelled by a cylinder and that errors have caused the points not to be exactly on the cylinder.

It's very easy to use:

```py
from cylinder_fitting import fit
w_fit, C_fit, r_fit, fit_err = fit(data)
```

[image]

I have also developed an object-oriented implementation of xingjiepan's repo with input validation and type hints. You can find it [here](https://github.com/CristianoPizzamiglio/py-cylinder-fitting) and can be used as follows:

```py
>>> from py_cylinder_fitting import BestFitCylinder
>>> from skspatial.objects import Points
>>> points = [[2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, -2, 0], [2, 0, 4], [0, 2, 4], [0, -2, 4]]
>>> best_fit_cylinder = BestFitCylinder(Points(points))
>>> best_fit_cylinder.point
[0., 0., 0.]
>>> best_fit_cylinder.vector
[0.  0.  4.]
>>> best_fit_cylinder.radius
2.0
```

We are also working to add this feature to the [scikit-spatial](https://github.com/ajhynes7/scikit-spatial) library.