# fit 3D cylinder in a point cloud

Tags: python, 3d, computer-vision, point-clouds, scipy-optimize

I am a bit confused. I have x,y,z points from a point cloud and I want to fit a cylinder using scipy and python.

The cylinder equation that I usually find on internet is `(x - a)**2 + (y - b)**2 = r**2` but I also want z to exist as parameter in this equation so I used also  `(x - a)**2 + (y - b)**2 + (z - c)**2 = r**2` but this is the equation for a sphere. I have used both to experiment.
My issue is that when I plot the predicted points (x_test, y_test, z_predicted) using the sphere formula, the points are not close to x_test, y_test, z_test. The same happens when I use the typical cylinder formula.
So I am asking, which is the correct formula to use to fit x,y,z on a cylinder which might not be parallel with any axis?

I am giving the code and some points to experiment.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from cfg_fit_cylinder import *

# Define the cylinder equation
def cylinder_equation(params, xyz):
    a, b, c, r = params
    x, y, z = xyz
    return (x - a)**2 + (y - b)**2 + (z - c)**2 - r**2

def cost_function(params, xyz_data):
    a, b, c, r = params
    total_error = 0
    for x, y, z in xyz_data:
        error = ((x - a)**2 + (y - b)**2 + (z - c)**2 - r**2)**2
        total_error += error
    return total_error

# Plot 3D points
def plot_3d_points(vertices, xyz_test, a, b, c, r):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')  # For the 3D points
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')  # For the cylinder surface

    x, y, z = vertices['x'], vertices['y'], vertices['z'] # Unscaled inital points
    ax1.scatter(x, y, z, c='b', marker='o')
    xyz_test = scaler.inverse_transform(xyz_test)
    ax1.scatter(xyz_test[:, 0], xyz_test[:, 1], xyz_test[:, 2], c='r', marker='x')
    ax1.set_xlabel('X Label')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Y Label')
    ax1.set_zlabel('Z Label')

    # Also unscaled
    resolution = 100
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, resolution)
    z_surface = np.linspace(min(z), max(z), resolution) #here
    Z, Theta = np.meshgrid(z_surface, theta)
    X = a + r * np.cos(Theta)
    Y = b + r * np.sin(Theta)
    ax2.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='Greens', alpha=1)

    predicted_z = np.array([cylinder_equation([a, b, c, r], xyz) for xyz in xyz_test]) # Unscaled test points/parameters
    shift_z = predicted_z - xyz_test[:, 2]

    # Plot the points with the z-shift
    ax1.scatter(xyz_test[:, 0], xyz_test[:, 1], xyz_test[:, 2] + shift_z, c='black', marker='x')

    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Load data
    points = pd.read_csv(PATH_TO_POINT_CLOUD, header=None)
    points.columns = ['x', 'y', 'z']

    # Scale data
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    points_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(points)

    params_list = []
    rmse_list = []
    result_list = []
    num_samples = [i for i in range(7, 3300, 100)]

    for num in num_samples:
        points_scaled_sampled = points_scaled[np.random.choice(len(points_scaled), num, replace=False)]

        train, test = train_test_split(points_scaled_sampled, test_size=0.3) # here

        # Initial guess based on data statistics
        initial_guess = [np.mean(train[:, 0]), np.mean(train[:, 1]), np.mean(train[:, 2]), 
                        np.std(np.linalg.norm(train - np.mean(train, axis=0), axis=1))]

        # Use the 'trust-constr' method for optimization
        result = minimize(cost_function, initial_guess, args=(train,), method='trust-constr')
        result_list.append(result)
        print('Optimization result:')
        print(result)
        print("========")
        params = result.x
        params_list.append(params)

        cylinder_values = np.array([cylinder_equation(params, xyz) for xyz in train])

        ssr = np.mean(cylinder_values**2)
        rmse = np.sqrt(ssr)
        rmse_list.append(rmse)

        print(f'RMSE, Samples: {round(rmse, 3)}, {num}')

    print('========')
    print(f'Min RMSE, samples: {round(min(rmse_list), 2)}, {num_samples[np.argmin(rmse_list)]}, Max RMSE, samples: {round(max(rmse_list), 2)}, {num_samples[np.argmax(rmse_list)]}')

    min_params = params_list[np.argmin(rmse_list)]
    a_min, b_min, c_min, r_min = min_params[0], min_params[1], min_params[2], min_params[3]

    # Denormalize parameters
    denormalized_params = scaler.inverse_transform([[a_min, b_min, c_min]])[0]
    a_min, b_min, c_min = denormalized_params

    # Denormalize r
    r_min = r_min * scaler.scale_[2] + scaler.mean_[2]

    plot_3d_points(points, test, a_min, b_min, c_min, r_min)
    plt.plot(num_samples, rmse_list)
```

and some points

```
-0.19509,-0.980785,9.66
-0.707107,-0.707107,9.66
-0.83147,-0.55557,9.66
-0.92388,-0.382683,-9.66
-0.92388,-0.382683,9.66
-0.980785,-0.19509,-9.66
-0.980785,-0.19509,9.66
-1.0,0.0,9.66
-0.980785,0.19509,-9.66
-0.707107,0.707107,-9.66
-0.55557,0.83147,-9.66
-0.097545,-0.990393,9.66
-0.19509,-0.980785,0.0
-0.288887,-0.952332,-9.66
-0.469127,-0.877675,9.66
-0.55557,-0.83147,0.0
-0.631338,-0.769288,-9.66
-0.631338,-0.769288,9.66
-0.769288,-0.631338,9.66
-0.877675,-0.469127,-9.66
-0.877675,-0.469127,9.66
-0.92388,-0.382683,0.0
-0.952332,-0.288887,-9.66
-0.952332,-0.288887,9.66
-0.980785,-0.19509,0.0
-0.990393,-0.097545,-9.66
-0.990393,-0.097545,9.66
-1.0,0.0,0.0
-0.990393,0.097545,-9.66
-0.990393,0.097545,9.66
-0.980785,0.19509,0.0
-0.877675,0.469127,-9.66
-0.877675,0.469127,9.66
-0.83147,0.55557,0.0
-0.769288,0.631338,9.66
-0.631338,0.769288,-9.66
-0.55557,0.83147,0.0
-0.469127,0.877675,-9.66
-0.952332,0.288887,0.0
-0.990393,-0.097545,0.0
-0.952332,-0.288887,0.0
-0.877675,-0.469127,0.0
-0.631338,-0.769288,0.0
-0.097545,-0.990393,0.0
0.097545,-0.990393,0.0
-0.048773,-0.995196,9.66
-0.19509,-0.980785,-4.83
-0.335785,-0.938106,-9.66
-0.425905,-0.900777,9.66
-0.55557,-0.83147,-4.83
-0.669223,-0.738197,-9.66
-0.593454,-0.800379,9.66
-0.738197,-0.669223,9.66
-0.83147,-0.55557,-4.83
-0.900777,-0.425905,-9.66
-0.854572,-0.512349,9.66
-0.92388,-0.382683,-4.83
-0.966559,-0.241989,-9.66
-0.938106,-0.335785,9.66
-0.980785,-0.19509,-4.83
-0.985589,-0.146318,9.66
-0.985589,0.146318,-9.66
-0.938106,0.335785,-9.66
-0.966559,0.241989,9.66
-0.900777,0.425905,9.66
-0.83147,0.55557,-4.83
-0.593454,0.800379,-9.66
0.0,-1.0,4.83
-0.146318,-0.985589,9.66
-0.19509,-0.980785,4.83
-0.382683,-0.92388,4.83
-0.55557,-0.83147,4.83
-0.738197,-0.669223,-9.66
-0.800379,-0.593454,9.66
-0.92388,-0.382683,4.83
-0.938106,-0.335785,-9.66
-0.966559,-0.241989,9.66
-0.985589,-0.146318,-9.66
-0.995196,-0.048773,9.66
-0.938106,0.335785,9.66
-0.707107,0.707107,4.83
-0.669223,0.738197,-9.66
-0.512349,0.854572,-9.66
-0.469127,0.877675,-4.83
-0.631338,0.769288,-4.83
-0.877675,0.469127,4.83
-0.952332,0.288887,4.83
-0.985589,0.146318,0.0
-0.990393,0.097545,-4.83
-0.990393,0.097545,4.83
-0.995196,-0.048773,0.0
-0.985589,-0.146318,0.0
-0.990393,-0.097545,-4.83
-0.990393,-0.097545,4.83
-0.966559,-0.241989,0.0
-0.938106,-0.335785,0.0
-0.952332,-0.288887,-4.83
-0.952332,-0.288887,4.83
-0.900777,-0.425905,0.0
-0.854572,-0.512349,0.0
-0.877675,-0.469127,-4.83
-0.738197,-0.669223,0.0
-0.769288,-0.631338,-4.83
-0.769288,-0.631338,4.83
-0.593454,-0.800379,0.0
-0.631338,-0.769288,-4.83
-0.631338,-0.769288,4.83
-0.425905,-0.900777,0.0
-0.288887,-0.952332,4.83
-0.048773,-0.995196,0.0
-0.335785,-0.938106,-4.83
-0.425905,-0.900777,4.83
-0.425905,-0.900777,-4.83
-0.593454,-0.800379,4.83
-0.593454,-0.800379,-4.83
-0.738197,-0.669223,4.83
-0.800379,-0.593454,-4.83
-0.854572,-0.512349,4.83
-0.854572,-0.512349,-4.83
-0.938106,-0.335785,4.83
-0.938106,-0.335785,-4.83
-0.966559,-0.241989,-4.83
-0.985589,-0.146318,4.83
-0.995196,-0.048773,-4.83
-0.966559,0.241989,4.83
-0.738197,0.669223,-4.83
-0.512349,0.854572,-4.83
-0.938106,0.335785,4.83
-0.995196,-0.048773,4.83
-0.966559,-0.241989,4.83
-0.900777,-0.425905,4.83
-0.800379,-0.593454,4.83
-0.533959,-0.843021,-9.66
-0.55557,-0.83147,-7.245
-0.688165,-0.722652,-9.66
-0.722652,-0.688165,9.66
-0.83147,-0.55557,-7.245
-0.912328,-0.404294,-9.66
-0.843021,-0.533959,9.66
-0.92388,-0.382683,-7.245
-0.973672,-0.218539,-9.66
-0.930993,-0.359234,9.66
-0.980785,-0.19509,-7.245
-0.983187,-0.170704,9.66
-1.0,0.0,-7.245
-0.997598,0.024386,9.66
-0.973672,0.218539,9.66
-0.92388,0.382683,-7.245
-0.912328,0.404294,9.66
-0.722652,0.688165,-9.66
-0.574512,0.815924,-9.66
-0.55557,0.83147,-7.245
-0.121931,-0.987991,9.66
-0.19509,-0.980785,2.415
-0.265438,-0.959446,-9.66
-0.447516,-0.889226,-9.66
-0.490738,-0.866123,9.66
-0.753743,-0.650281,-9.66
-0.784834,-0.612396,9.66
-0.83147,-0.55557,2.415
-0.889226,-0.447516,9.66
-0.92388,-0.382683,2.415
-0.945219,-0.312336,-9.66
-0.959446,-0.265438,9.66
-0.987991,0.121931,9.66
-0.959446,0.265438,-9.66
-0.866123,0.490738,9.66
-0.650281,0.753743,-9.66
-0.55557,0.83147,2.415
-0.490738,0.866123,-9.66
-0.574512,0.815924,0.0
-0.631338,0.769288,-7.245
-0.631338,0.769288,2.415
-0.769288,0.631338,-7.245
-0.769288,0.631338,2.415
-0.952332,0.288887,2.415
-0.992795,0.073159,0.0
-0.990393,0.097545,-7.245
-0.997598,-0.024386,0.0
-0.987991,-0.121931,0.0
-0.973672,-0.218539,0.0
-0.945219,-0.312336,0.0
-0.952332,-0.288887,-7.245
-0.952332,-0.288887,2.415
-0.912328,-0.404294,0.0
-0.866123,-0.490738,0.0
-0.877675,-0.469127,-7.245
-0.877675,-0.469127,2.415
-0.815924,-0.574512,0.0
-0.769288,-0.631338,-7.245
-0.688165,-0.722652,0.0
-0.631338,-0.769288,2.415
-0.533959,-0.843021,0.0
-0.359234,-0.930993,0.0
-0.265438,-0.959446,0.0
-0.288887,-0.952332,2.415
-0.097545,-0.990393,2.415
-0.073159,-0.992795,9.66
-0.265438,-0.959446,9.66
-0.382683,-0.92388,-2.415
-0.490738,-0.866123,-9.66
-0.784834,-0.612396,-9.66
-0.753743,-0.650281,9.66
-0.83147,-0.55557,-2.415
-0.866123,-0.490738,9.66
-0.92388,-0.382683,-2.415
-0.959446,-0.265438,-9.66
-0.945219,-0.312336,9.66
-0.980785,-0.19509,-2.415
-0.992795,-0.073159,-9.66
-0.987991,-0.121931,9.66
-0.987991,0.121931,-9.66
-0.992795,0.073159,9.66
-0.889226,0.447516,9.66
-0.784834,0.612396,9.66
-0.612396,0.784834,-9.66
-0.447516,0.889226,-9.66
0.218539,-0.973672,9.66
-0.170704,-0.983187,9.66
-0.19509,-0.980785,7.245
-0.359234,-0.930993,9.66
-0.533959,-0.843021,9.66
-0.55557,-0.83147,7.245
-0.722652,-0.688165,-9.66
-0.912328,-0.404294,9.66
-0.92388,-0.382683,7.245
-0.930993,-0.359234,-9.66
-0.980785,-0.19509,7.245
-0.983187,-0.170704,-9.66
-0.997598,-0.024386,9.66
-1.0,0.0,7.245
-0.983187,0.170704,9.66
-0.973672,0.218539,-9.66
-0.930993,0.359234,9.66
-0.83147,0.55557,7.245
-0.688165,0.722652,-9.66
-0.688165,0.722652,0.0
-0.877675,0.469127,7.245
-0.952332,0.288887,7.245
-0.987991,0.121931,0.0
-0.990393,0.097545,-2.415
-0.992795,-0.073159,0.0
-0.983187,-0.170704,0.0
-0.990393,-0.097545,-2.415
-0.990393,-0.097545,7.245
-0.959446,-0.265438,0.0
-0.930993,-0.359234,0.0
-0.952332,-0.288887,-2.415
-0.952332,-0.288887,7.245
-0.877675,-0.469127,-2.415
-0.784834,-0.612396,0.0
-0.722652,-0.688165,0.0
-0.769288,-0.631338,-2.415
-0.631338,-0.769288,-2.415
-0.631338,-0.769288,7.245
-0.490738,-0.866123,0.0
-0.312336,-0.945219,0.0
-0.218539,-0.973672,0.0
-0.121931,-0.987991,0.0
-0.097545,-0.990393,-2.415
-0.048773,-0.995196,2.415
-0.048773,-0.995196,7.245
-0.048773,-0.995196,-2.415
-0.170704,-0.983187,-4.83
-0.265438,-0.959446,4.83
-0.218539,-0.973672,-4.83
-0.241989,-0.966559,-2.415
-0.359234,-0.930993,-4.83
-0.335785,-0.938106,-7.245
-0.447516,-0.889226,4.83
-0.425905,-0.900777,2.415
-0.425905,-0.900777,7.245
-0.447516,-0.889226,-4.83
-0.425905,-0.900777,-7.245
-0.425905,-0.900777,-2.415
-0.533959,-0.843021,-4.83
-0.490738,-0.866123,-4.83
-0.593454,-0.800379,2.415
-0.593454,-0.800379,7.245
-0.612396,-0.784834,-4.83
-0.593454,-0.800379,-7.245
-0.593454,-0.800379,-2.415
-0.688165,-0.722652,-4.83
-0.650281,-0.753743,-4.83
-0.753743,-0.650281,4.83
-0.722652,-0.688165,4.83
-0.738197,-0.669223,7.245
-0.722652,-0.688165,-4.83
-0.738197,-0.669223,-7.245
-0.738197,-0.669223,-2.415
-0.784834,-0.612396,-4.83
-0.800379,-0.593454,-7.245
-0.800379,-0.593454,-2.415
-0.866123,-0.490738,4.83
-0.843021,-0.533959,4.83
-0.854572,-0.512349,2.415
-0.854572,-0.512349,7.245
-0.866123,-0.490738,-4.83
-0.854572,-0.512349,-7.245
-0.854572,-0.512349,-2.415
-0.889226,-0.447516,-4.83
-0.900777,-0.425905,-7.245
-0.900777,-0.425905,-2.415
-0.945219,-0.312336,4.83
-0.930993,-0.359234,4.83
-0.938106,-0.335785,2.415
-0.938106,-0.335785,7.245
-0.945219,-0.312336,-4.83
-0.930993,-0.359234,-4.83
-0.938106,-0.335785,-7.245
-0.938106,-0.335785,-2.415
-0.973672,-0.218539,-4.83
-0.959446,-0.265438,-4.83
-0.966559,-0.241989,-7.245
-0.966559,-0.241989,-2.415
-0.987991,-0.121931,4.83
-0.985589,-0.146318,7.245
-0.987991,-0.121931,-4.83
-0.983187,-0.170704,-4.83
-0.985589,-0.146318,-7.245
-0.992795,-0.073159,-4.83
-0.995196,-0.048773,-7.245
-0.995196,-0.048773,-2.415
-0.992795,0.073159,4.83
-0.997598,0.024386,4.83
-0.995196,0.048773,2.415
-0.995196,0.048773,7.245
-0.992795,0.073159,-4.83
-0.995196,0.048773,-2.415
-0.985589,0.146318,-7.245
-0.985589,0.146318,-2.415
-0.973672,0.218539,4.83
-0.966559,0.241989,2.415
-0.966559,0.241989,-2.415
-0.889226,0.447516,4.83
-0.912328,0.404294,4.83
-0.900777,0.425905,7.245
-0.815924,0.574512,-4.83
-0.738197,0.669223,-2.415
-0.669223,0.738197,2.415
-0.669223,0.738197,7.245
-0.593454,0.800379,-7.245
-0.593454,0.800379,-2.415
-0.490738,0.866123,-4.83
-0.593454,0.800379,2.415
-0.930993,0.359234,4.83
-0.945219,0.312336,4.83
-0.938106,0.335785,2.415
-0.983187,0.170704,4.83
-0.985589,0.146318,2.415
-0.997598,-0.024386,4.83
-0.992795,-0.073159,4.83
-0.995196,-0.048773,2.415
-0.995196,-0.048773,7.245
-0.973672,-0.218539,4.83
-0.959446,-0.265438,4.83
-0.966559,-0.241989,2.415
-0.966559,-0.241989,7.245
-0.900777,-0.425905,2.415
-0.900777,-0.425905,7.245
-0.815924,-0.574512,4.83
-0.784834,-0.612396,4.83
-0.800379,-0.593454,2.415
-0.688165,-0.722652,4.83
-0.650281,-0.753743,4.83
-0.533959,-0.843021,4.83
-0.490738,-0.866123,4.83
-0.359234,-0.930993,4.83
-0.170704,-0.983187,4.83
0.024386,-0.997598,4.83
0.048773,-0.995196,2.415
0.048773,-0.995196,7.245
0.073159,-0.992795,2.415
-0.121931,-0.987991,7.245
-0.121931,-0.987991,2.415
-0.170704,-0.983187,2.415
-0.312336,-0.945219,2.415
-0.359234,-0.930993,2.415
-0.490738,-0.866123,7.245
-0.490738,-0.866123,2.415
-0.533959,-0.843021,2.415
-0.650281,-0.753743,2.415
-0.688165,-0.722652,2.415
-0.784834,-0.612396,7.245
-0.784834,-0.612396,2.415
-0.815924,-0.574512,2.415
-0.889226,-0.447516,7.245
-0.889226,-0.447516,2.415
-0.959446,-0.265438,7.245
-0.959446,-0.265438,2.415
-0.973672,-0.218539,2.415
-0.992795,-0.073159,7.245
-0.992795,-0.073159,2.415
-0.997598,-0.024386,2.415
-0.987991,0.121931,7.245
-0.987991,0.121931,2.415
-0.945219,0.312336,7.245
-0.930993,0.359234,2.415
-0.753743,0.650281,2.415
-0.574512,0.815924,2.415
-0.533959,0.843021,-7.245
-0.574512,0.815924,-7.245
-0.650281,0.753743,-7.245
-0.688165,0.722652,2.415
-0.784834,0.612396,2.415
-0.889226,0.447516,-7.245
-0.912328,0.404294,7.245
-0.973672,0.218539,7.245
-0.973672,0.218539,2.415
-0.997598,0.024386,-2.415
-0.997598,0.024386,-7.245
-0.997598,0.024386,2.415
-0.992795,0.073159,2.415
-0.992795,-0.073159,-2.415
-0.992795,-0.073159,-7.245
-0.983187,-0.170704,-2.415
-0.987991,-0.121931,-7.245
-0.983187,-0.170704,2.415
-0.987991,-0.121931,2.415
-0.959446,-0.265438,-2.415
-0.959446,-0.265438,-7.245
-0.973672,-0.218539,-7.245
-0.930993,-0.359234,-2.415
-0.930993,-0.359234,-7.245
-0.945219,-0.312336,-7.245
-0.930993,-0.359234,7.245
-0.930993,-0.359234,2.415
-0.945219,-0.312336,2.415
-0.889226,-0.447516,-2.415
-0.889226,-0.447516,-7.245
-0.912328,-0.404294,-7.245
-0.843021,-0.533959,-2.415
-0.843021,-0.533959,-7.245
-0.843021,-0.533959,7.245
-0.843021,-0.533959,2.415
-0.784834,-0.612396,-2.415
-0.784834,-0.612396,-7.245
-0.722652,-0.688165,-2.415
-0.722652,-0.688165,-7.245
-0.753743,-0.650281,-7.245
-0.722652,-0.688165,7.245
-0.722652,-0.688165,2.415
-0.753743,-0.650281,2.415
-0.650281,-0.753743,-2.415
-0.650281,-0.753743,-7.245
-0.688165,-0.722652,-7.245
-0.490738,-0.866123,-2.415
-0.490738,-0.866123,-7.245
-0.533959,-0.843021,-7.245
-0.218539,-0.973672,-2.415
-0.218539,-0.973672,-7.245
-0.218539,-0.973672,2.415
-0.265438,-0.959446,2.415
-0.121931,-0.987991,-2.415
-0.170704,-0.983187,-2.415
-0.265438,-0.959446,7.245
-0.265438,-0.959446,-2.415
-0.359234,-0.930993,-2.415
-0.447516,-0.889226,7.245
-0.447516,-0.889226,-2.415
-0.533959,-0.843021,-2.415
-0.688165,-0.722652,-2.415
-0.753743,-0.650281,7.245
-0.753743,-0.650281,-2.415
-0.866123,-0.490738,7.245
-0.866123,-0.490738,-2.415
-0.945219,-0.312336,7.245
-0.945219,-0.312336,-2.415
-0.973672,-0.218539,-2.415
-0.987991,-0.121931,-2.415
-0.997598,-0.024386,-2.415
-0.992795,0.073159,7.245
-0.959446,0.265438,7.245
-0.574512,0.815924,-2.415
-0.843021,0.533959,7.245
-0.983187,0.170704,7.245
-0.997598,-0.024386,7.245
-0.973672,-0.218539,7.245
-0.912328,-0.404294,7.245
-0.815924,-0.574512,7.245
-0.688165,-0.722652,7.245
-0.533959,-0.843021,7.245
-0.170704,-0.983187,7.245
-0.206815,-0.977229,9.66
-0.697636,-0.714879,-9.66
-0.823697,-0.565041,-9.66
-0.83147,-0.55557,-8.452499
-0.918104,-0.393489,-9.66
-0.92388,-0.382683,-8.452499
-0.927436,-0.370959,9.66
-0.980785,-0.19509,-8.452499
-0.981986,-0.182897,9.66
-0.998799,0.012193,9.66
-0.918104,0.393489,9.66
-0.565041,0.823697,-9.66
-0.19509,-0.980785,1.2075
-0.479932,-0.871899,9.66
-0.55557,-0.83147,1.2075
-0.64081,-0.761515,9.66
-0.761515,-0.64081,-9.66
-0.871899,-0.479932,-9.66
-0.88345,-0.458321,9.66
-0.92388,-0.382683,1.2075
-0.948776,-0.300611,-9.66
-0.955889,-0.277162,9.66
-0.980785,-0.19509,1.2075
-0.989192,-0.109738,-9.66
-0.991594,-0.085352,9.66
-1.0,0.0,1.2075
-0.948776,0.300611,9.66
-0.92388,0.382683,1.2075
-0.761515,0.64081,9.66
-0.64081,0.761515,-9.66
-0.479932,0.871899,-9.66
-0.565041,0.823697,0.0
-0.631338,0.769288,-8.452499
-0.714879,0.697636,0.0
-0.777061,0.621867,0.0
-0.952332,0.288887,1.2075
-0.991594,0.085352,0.0
-0.990393,-0.097545,1.2075
-0.948776,-0.300611,0.0
-0.952332,-0.288887,-8.452499
-0.952332,-0.288887,1.2075
-0.918104,-0.393489,0.0
-0.871899,-0.479932,0.0
-0.877675,-0.469127,-8.452499
-0.877675,-0.469127,1.2075
-0.823697,-0.565041,0.0
-0.761515,-0.64081,0.0
-0.631338,-0.769288,1.2075
-0.544765,-0.837245,0.0
-0.370959,-0.927436,0.0
-0.277162,-0.955889,0.0
-0.288887,-0.952332,-8.452499
-0.288887,-0.952332,1.2075
-0.182897,-0.981986,0.0
-0.085352,-0.991594,0.0
-0.097545,-0.990393,1.2075
0.097545,-0.990393,1.2075
-0.060966,-0.993995,9.66
-0.382683,-0.92388,-3.6225
-0.501543,-0.860348,-9.66
-0.707107,-0.707107,-3.6225
-0.74597,-0.659752,9.66
-0.83147,-0.55557,-3.6225
-0.92388,-0.382683,-3.6225
-0.963002,-0.253713,-9.66
-0.941663,-0.324061,9.66
-0.980785,-0.19509,-3.6225
-0.98679,-0.134125,9.66
-0.993995,0.060966,9.66
-0.980785,0.19509,-3.6225
-0.707107,0.707107,-3.6225
-0.19509,-0.980785,6.0375
-0.34751,-0.934549,9.66
-0.4151,-0.906553,-9.66
-0.678694,-0.730425,9.66
-0.92388,-0.382683,6.0375
-0.970115,-0.230264,9.66
-0.980785,-0.19509,6.0375
-0.984388,-0.158511,-9.66
-0.996397,-0.036579,9.66
-1.0,0.0,6.0375
-0.980785,0.19509,6.0375
-0.848796,0.523154,9.66
-0.808152,0.583983,-9.66
-0.678694,0.730425,-9.66
-0.769288,0.631338,-3.6225
-0.877675,0.469127,6.0375
-0.952332,0.288887,6.0375
-0.98679,0.134125,0.0
-0.993995,-0.060966,0.0
-0.984388,-0.158511,0.0
-0.990393,-0.097545,-3.6225
-0.990393,-0.097545,6.0375
-0.963002,-0.253713,0.0
-0.934549,-0.34751,0.0
-0.952332,-0.288887,-3.6225
-0.952332,-0.288887,6.0375
-0.895001,-0.436711,0.0
-0.877675,-0.469127,-3.6225
-0.792606,-0.602925,0.0
-0.769288,-0.631338,-3.6225
-0.583983,-0.808152,0.0
-0.631338,-0.769288,-3.6225
-0.631338,-0.769288,6.0375
-0.4151,-0.906553,0.0
-0.230264,-0.970115,0.0
-0.288887,-0.952332,6.0375
-0.048773,-0.995196,6.0375
-0.277162,-0.955889,4.83
-0.230264,-0.970115,4.83
-0.335785,-0.938106,-3.6225
-0.4151,-0.906553,4.83
-0.425905,-0.900777,1.2075
-0.425905,-0.900777,6.0375
-0.4151,-0.906553,-4.83
-0.544765,-0.837245,-4.83
-0.583983,-0.808152,4.83
-0.593454,-0.800379,1.2075
-0.593454,-0.800379,6.0375
-0.583983,-0.808152,-4.83
-0.593454,-0.800379,-8.452499
-0.593454,-0.800379,-3.6225
-0.761515,-0.64081,4.83
-0.761515,-0.64081,-4.83
-0.738197,-0.669223,-3.6225
-0.823697,-0.565041,-4.83
-0.792606,-0.602925,-4.83
-0.800379,-0.593454,-8.452499
-0.800379,-0.593454,-3.6225
-0.871899,-0.479932,4.83
-0.848796,-0.523154,4.83
-0.854572,-0.512349,1.2075
-0.854572,-0.512349,6.0375
-0.871899,-0.479932,-4.83
-0.854572,-0.512349,-8.452499
-0.854572,-0.512349,-3.6225
-0.895001,-0.436711,-4.83
-0.900777,-0.425905,-8.452499
-0.900777,-0.425905,-3.6225
-0.948776,-0.300611,4.83
-0.934549,-0.34751,4.83
-0.938106,-0.335785,1.2075
-0.938106,-0.335785,6.0375
-0.948776,-0.300611,-4.83
-0.934549,-0.34751,-4.83
-0.938106,-0.335785,-8.452499
-0.938106,-0.335785,-3.6225
-0.963002,-0.253713,-4.83
-0.966559,-0.241989,-8.452499
-0.966559,-0.241989,-3.6225
-0.984388,-0.158511,4.83
-0.985589,-0.146318,6.0375
-0.989192,-0.109738,-4.83
-0.995196,-0.048773,-3.6225
-0.996397,0.036579,-4.83
-0.985589,0.146318,-3.6225
-0.970115,0.230264,4.83
-0.966559,0.241989,1.2075
-0.966559,0.241989,6.0375
-0.906553,0.4151,4.83
-0.900777,0.425905,6.0375
-0.88345,0.458321,-4.83
-0.900777,0.425905,-8.452499
-0.854572,0.512349,-8.452499
-0.800379,0.593454,-8.452499
-0.738197,0.669223,-3.6225
-0.64081,0.761515,-4.83
-0.593454,0.800379,-8.452499
-0.512349,0.854572,-8.452499
-0.981986,0.182897,4.83
-0.995196,-0.048773,6.0375
-0.977229,-0.206815,4.83
-0.963002,-0.253713,4.83
-0.966559,-0.241989,1.2075
-0.966559,-0.241989,6.0375
-0.918104,-0.393489,4.83
-0.900777,-0.425905,1.2075
-0.900777,-0.425905,6.0375
-0.792606,-0.602925,4.83
-0.659752,-0.74597,4.83
-0.544765,-0.837245,4.83
-0.501543,-0.860348,4.83
-0.512349,-0.854572,1.2075
-0.182897,-0.981986,4.83
-0.134125,-0.98679,4.83
0.048773,-0.995196,1.2075
-0.230264,-0.970115,9.66
-0.382683,-0.92388,-6.0375
-0.4151,-0.906553,9.66
-0.678694,-0.730425,-9.66
-0.583983,-0.808152,9.66
-0.83147,-0.55557,-6.0375
-0.92388,-0.382683,-6.0375
-0.970115,-0.230264,-9.66
-0.934549,-0.34751,9.66
-0.984388,0.158511,-9.66
-0.970115,0.230264,9.66
-0.808152,0.583983,9.66
-0.583983,0.808152,-9.66
-0.55557,0.83147,-6.0375
-0.19509,-0.980785,3.6225
-0.55557,-0.83147,3.6225
-0.792606,-0.602925,9.66
-0.83147,-0.55557,3.6225
-0.92388,-0.382683,3.6225
-0.941663,-0.324061,-9.66
-0.963002,-0.253713,9.66
-0.980785,-0.19509,3.6225
-0.98679,0.134125,9.66
-0.707107,0.707107,3.6225
-0.501543,0.860348,-9.66
-0.952332,0.288887,3.6225
-0.990393,0.097545,3.6225
-0.990393,-0.097545,3.6225
-0.941663,-0.324061,0.0
-0.952332,-0.288887,-6.0375
-0.877675,-0.469127,-6.0375
-0.877675,-0.469127,3.6225
-0.769288,-0.631338,3.6225
-0.631338,-0.769288,-6.0375
-0.631338,-0.769288,3.6225
-0.436711,-0.895001,0.0
-0.34751,-0.934549,0.0
-0.288887,-0.952332,-6.0375
-0.288887,-0.952332,3.6225
-0.085352,-0.991594,9.66
-0.300611,-0.948776,-9.66
-0.64081,-0.761515,-9.66
-0.707107,-0.707107,-1.2075
-0.871899,-0.479932,9.66
-0.92388,-0.382683,-1.2075
-0.955889,-0.277162,-9.66
-0.948776,-0.300611,9.66
-0.980785,-0.19509,-1.2075
-1.0,0.0,-1.2075
-0.980785,0.19509,-1.2075
-0.955889,0.277162,9.66
-0.88345,0.458321,9.66
-0.621867,0.777061,-9.66
-0.55557,0.83147,-1.2075
-0.458321,0.88345,-9.66
-0.182897,-0.981986,9.66
-0.19509,-0.980785,8.452499
-0.370959,-0.927436,9.66
-0.544765,-0.837245,9.66
-0.83147,-0.55557,8.452499
-0.92388,-0.382683,8.452499
-0.980785,-0.19509,8.452499
-0.981986,0.182897,9.66
-0.980785,0.19509,8.452499
-0.92388,0.382683,8.452499
-0.83147,0.55557,8.452499
-0.823697,0.565041,-9.66
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you. It includes orientation parameters fitting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44164662/13719353

Comment: An (infinite) cylinder is the surface of points which are a fixed distance from a line. Your arbitrary line in 3d space needs the coordinates of a point through which it passes and a vector along the line (which is unique only up to a scale factor).

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this problem by working out R from the data, rather than making it a parameter of the model. Essentially, you are trying to find the central axis of the cylinder, and you are trying to find one which is equidistant from all points.

You can do this by the following procedure:

1. Subtract the center of the cylinder from all points.
2. Project the point onto the central axis. This is the vector representing the closest central position to the point.
3. Subtract the vector from the point, and find the distance.
4. Get the standard deviation of all distances.
5. Minimize the standard deviation.

Once you know the position and direction of the central axis, you can find radius by following the same procedure up to step 3, and finding the mean of the distances instead of the standard deviation.

Height can by found by projecting the point onto the central axis, and taking the distance of that projection. The maximum distance gets you the height.

Here's the cylinder that procedure finds:

[image: cylinder]

(Blue is original points, orange is the fit.)

This parametrizes the cylinder using nine parameters:

- 3 for cylinder position,
- 3 for the direction of the central axis,
- 1 for radius, and
- 2 for height. (This uses two because it tracks height above and height below the center separately.)

This should be able to find cylinders of arbitrary position, size, and rotation.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, basinhopping, brute
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA


PATH_TO_POINT_CLOUD = "test537.csv"
points = pd.read_csv(PATH_TO_POINT_CLOUD, header=None)
points.columns = ['x', 'y', 'z']


def proj(x, y):
    if x.shape == y.shape:
        # single x vector
        return y * (np.dot(x, y) / np.dot(y, y))
    else:
        # broadcast along x
        return y[np.newaxis, :] * (np.dot(x, y) / np.dot(y, y))[:, np.newaxis]


def scalar_proj(x, y):
    if x.shape == y.shape:
        # single x vector
        return (np.dot(x, y) / np.dot(y, y))
    else:
        # broadcast along x
        return (np.dot(x, y) / np.dot(y, y))[:, np.newaxis]
    
    
def normalize(v):
    norm = np.linalg.norm(v)
    if norm == 0: 
        raise Exception("Division by zero in normalize")
    return v / norm


def distance_from_central_axis(cyl_center, cyl_vec, point_vec):
    cyl_vec = normalize(cyl_vec)
    point_offset = point_vec - cyl_center
    center_to_point = point_offset - proj(point_offset, cyl_vec)
    distance = np.linalg.norm(center_to_point, axis=1)
    return distance


def distance_along_central_axis(cyl_center, cyl_vec, point_vec):
    cyl_vec = normalize(cyl_vec)
    point_offset = point_vec - cyl_center
    signed_distance_along_central_axis = scalar_proj(point_offset, cyl_vec)
    return signed_distance_along_central_axis


def cylinder_radius(cyl_center, cyl_vec, point_vec):
    return np.mean(distance_from_central_axis(cyl_center, cyl_vec, point_vec))


def cylinder_height(cyl_center, cyl_vec, point_vec):
    distance = distance_along_central_axis(cyl_center, cyl_vec, point_vec)
    return np.min(distance), np.max(distance)


def cost_func(x, points):
    a, b, c, d, e, f = x
    cyl_center = np.array([a, b, c])
    cyl_vec = np.array([d, e, f])
    distances = distance_from_central_axis(cyl_center, cyl_vec, points)
    # Minimize variance of distance
    cost = np.std(distances)
    # Also penalize having center off-center
    off_center_penalty = distance_along_central_axis(cyl_center, cyl_vec, points).mean()
    cost += off_center_penalty ** 2
    return cost


def guess_cyl_vec(points):
    return PCA(n_components=1).fit(points).components_[0]


def find_cyl_center_and_vec(points, n_iter=10):
    points_npy = points.values
    
    # Note: this fit is running in a loop because I found that the minimizer
    # got trapped in local minima if provided with a bad initial guess.
    # To compensate for this, run the fit 10 times and pick the best one.
    best = None
    for i in range(n_iter):
        x0 = np.random.normal(scale=1e-3, size=6)
        # Use mean as position guess instead of random
        x0[0:3] = points_npy.mean(axis=0)
        options = {
            'eps': 1e-9
        }
        res = minimize(lambda x: cost_func(x, points_npy), x0=x0, options=options, method='BFGS')
        if best is None or res.fun < best.fun:
            best = res
    cyl_center, cyl_vec = best.x.reshape([2, 3])
    cyl_vec = normalize(cyl_vec)
    # Force Z to be non-negative
    if cyl_vec[2] < 0:
        cyl_vec = -cyl_vec
    return cyl_center, cyl_vec


def get_cylinder_points(cyl_center, cyl_vec, radius, height_min, height_max):
    t_height = np.linspace(height_min, height_max, 1000)[:, np.newaxis]
    turns = 10
    t_rot = np.linspace(0, 2*turns*np.pi, 1000)[:, np.newaxis]
    central_axis = cyl_center + t_height * cyl_vec[np.newaxis]
    # Get orthoganal vectors using Gramm-Schmitt
    rotvec1 = np.random.randn(3)
    rotvec1 -= rotvec1.dot(cyl_vec) * cyl_vec
    rotvec1 /= np.linalg.norm(rotvec1)
    rotvec2 = np.cross(cyl_vec, rotvec1)
    cylinder_points = central_axis.copy()
    cylinder_points += radius * np.cos(t_rot) * rotvec1[np.newaxis]
    cylinder_points += radius * np.sin(t_rot) * rotvec2[np.newaxis]
    return cylinder_points


cyl_center, cyl_vec = find_cyl_center_and_vec(points)
radius = cylinder_radius(cyl_center, cyl_vec, points.values)
height_min, height_max = cylinder_height(cyl_center, cyl_vec, points.values)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(*points.values.T)
ax.scatter(*get_cylinder_points(cyl_center, cyl_vec, radius, height_min, height_max).T)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It seems like a descent solution and thank you for that. Nevertheless, it seems like it can be greatly affected by outliers in real world scenarios like mine, which is point cloud from laser scanner.
I have solved the problem mainly using Principal Component Analysis, by projecting the points onto PC1 to get orientation and height and onto PC2 and PC3 plane to fit the projected points to circle and get the center and the radius of the circle (of the cylinder as well). A bunch of robust solutions accompanies the solution.

Comment: One can find the publication I referred here: https://isprs-archives.copernicus.org/articles/XLII-1-W1/63/2017/isprs-archives-XLII-1-W1-63-2017.html

Answer (score 0):

(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 = r^2 .

The meaning of the formula is for a circle with radius r and center at (a, b) on the xy-plane. The free unconstrained z-coordinate can have any value. Therefore, the formula is for a cylinder with radius r and z-axis as its orientation crossing the point (a, b, 0).

In order to represent an arbitrary cylinder in three-dimensional space, the position and axis direction must be added to the radius of the cylinder.

Your coordinate values were saved as an xyz-file and processed using FindSurface Web Demo (https://developers.curvsurf.com/WebDemo/).

[image: Stackoverflow_Cylinder]

Comment: That would be easy if i had points onto the two basis of the cylinder, but I have not. Imagine that the point cloud is detected by a lidar, which focuses on a pipe. It would detect only points on the surface of the cylinder. 

Also, I need to put the length as a parameter inside the equation. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: x^2 + y^2 = r^2 .

The above expression may represent a circle with radius r lying at the origin of the 2D xy-plane, but it may also represent a cylinder of radius r with the z-axis as its axis passing through the origin of the 3D xyz-space. The length of the cylinder is undetermined.

In order to represent an actual cylinder that exists in real 3D space, both end points of the cylinder must be added to the radius r. Furthermore, as examples of the surface ratio of a cylinder, full cylinder, semi-cylinder, quarter cylinder, etc. must be expressed.

Comment: The key task is to accurately obtain the radius, position, and axial direction (i.e., both end points) of a real cylinder.

In order to express the position Xo and direction R of an object in 2D or 3D space, the coordinate transformation x = R (X-Xo) must be added to the above equation.

Objects in 2D or 3D space have shape, size, position, and posture.

They all have to be obtained solely from measurement data, which is all we know, and sometimes require human intervention.